# What tool to use for this regex

Tags: regex, bash, automator, exiftool

I am using a combination of Automator, Bash, and Exiftool to take filenames like this: `0615090217.jpg` and change the date created to `2009:06:15 02:17:00`.

Most of the pieces of the puzzle are working, I even have working regex, I just don't know how to apply it using bash or some combination of other tools. I've been seeing sed suggested, but I don't know how to apply it.

The following regex works [here](http://regexr.com/3cgs3), but I don't know how to apply it in my setup:

- Expression: `/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(.*)\.[^.]+$/g`
- Substitution: `\n20$3:$1:$2 $4:$5:00\n\t`
- Text: `0615090217.jpg`

The shell script in my Automator workflow looks like this:

```
for f in "$@"
do
  FILENAME=$(basename "$f")
  MYDATE='2010:07:09 12:22:00'
  /usr/local/bin/exiftool -overwrite_original_in_place -preserve "-AllDates=${MYDATE}" "$f"
done
```

I want to replace MYDATE with a date extracted from the filename, using my regex or some other method. I feel like I'm close, it's just connecting the final dots.

Comment: I suggest to ask at [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Are you really asking what tool to use, or are you asking how you fix your bash script so that it changes the date format for use with exiftool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using OSX, FreeBSD, NetBSD, etc, then the `date` command lets you easily convert from one format to another:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for f in "$@"
do
  FILENAME=$(basename "$f")
  MYDATE=$(date -j -f '%m%d%y%H%M.jpg' "$FILENAME" '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00')
  /usr/local/bin/exiftool \
    -overwrite_original_in_place \
    -preserve "-AllDates=${MYDATE}" \
    "$f"
done
```

You can also achieve this by ripping apart the filename using bash's "Parameter Expansion", but that takes more typing.

Comment: Really close! I noticed one other bug, dates from 2010 are for some reason like `0709011222.jpg`, `01` in the %y. Any idea for a quick fix for that? I'll mark this accepted either way but it would be really helpful.

Comment: @bookcasey, Is it safe to assume that you will never have any files with dates from year 2001? (Note that this is a bug in whatever process generated your filenames, not a bug in the script above. You're asking for a workaround in the script to help you handle the bug in the file creation process.)

Answer (score 2):

Exiftool can do this by itself.  There's no need for scripts, since that would just slow the whole process down because it would call exiftool for each file.

Try something like:
`/usr/local/bin/exiftool -overwrite_original_in_place -preserve '-AllDates<${Filename;s/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(.*)\.[^.]+$/20$3:$1:$2 $4:$5:00/}' DIR`

I just lifted your regex and stuck it in, so test it out first, of course. My quick test here worked correctly, output below.

```
c:\>exiftool -g1 -alldates X:\!temp\0615090217.jpg
---- IFD0 ----
Modify Date                     : 2012:08:30 22:25:33
---- ExifIFD ----
Date/Time Original              : 2013:18:08 19:04:15
Create Date                     : 2012:08:30 22:25:33

c:\>exiftool "-AllDates<${Filename;s/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(.*)\.[^.]+$/20$3:$1:$2 $4:$5:00/}" X:\!temp\0615090217.jpg
1 image files updated

c:\>exiftool -g1 -alldates X:\!temp\0615090217.jpg
---- IFD0 ----
Modify Date                     : 2009:06:15 02:17:00
---- ExifIFD ----
Date/Time Original              : 2009:06:15 02:17:00
Create Date                     : 2009:06:15 02:17:00
```

Comment: Nice! +1 for knowing the tools better! :-)